# Html arrow characters aligned to bottom of font, how align to mid of font?

Tags: html, xml, characters

I want to use the following html charactes:

A←↞⇽

However, as you can see, the arrows are aligned bottom of the font's vertical center-line. Is there a way to "lift them" up to the vertical center of the font?

Comment: How hey render might depend on which browser and OS you are using. For me; Firefox on Ubuntu Linux renders the arrows in line (vertically) with the `-` of `A`

Comment: OK. I render on Android in xml. Is there something I can do? I have tried with gravity and stuff but doesn't help...

Comment: It depends upon the *font*.  Browser (usually) is irrelevant.  Here (OSX and Firefox), the last two characters are misaligned.

Comment: They are in line with - in A but still lower than mid if you feel me...